# ImportError: cannot import name '_get_logger'

Tags: tensorflow, niftynet

I'm trying to run Niftynet on my PC. but it keeps showing this error.

CPU version for tensorflow INFO:tensorflow:TensorFlow version 1.13.1

Do i need to install the tensorflow-gpu??

```
~/mlproject/test1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/niftynet/io/misc_io.py in set_logger(file_name)
    754     """
    755     # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
--> 756     from tensorflow.python.platform.tf_logging import _get_logger
    757 
    758     logger = _get_logger()

ImportError: cannot import name '_get_logger'
```

Answer (score 1):

just _get_logger -> get_logger

```
756     from tensorflow.python.platform.tf_logging import get_logger
757 
758     logger = get_logger()
```

and go to close_logger do same thing